# Accessing parent view buttons in container view controller

Tags: ios, swift3, collectionview, uicontainerview

I have a collection view controller inside of a container view and buttons on the parent view - I need my container view to be able to access the button outlets from my parent view so that I can detect when buttons are clicked in order modify my collection view (in container view) accordingly.

I tried to use preparesegue function but I couldn't get the code I had found to work.

Comment: Do you really need to touch the outlets or do you only need to be informed about clicks?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure.. my parent view is a filters menu with 3 buttons that act as radio buttons, two switches, and an "apply filters" button. So, I need to know when the user chooses to apply filters and then which selections were made. @PhillipMills

Comment: That sounds as if the parent just needs to forward its control actions to the contained view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `NotificationCenter`, have your buttons post the notification, and have your child view controller listen for them.

For example, in the parent VC, post the notification in the function called when a button is tapped, like so:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
     NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "ButtonTapped"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
}
```

In the child VC that needs to respond to the button tap, place the following code in `viewWillAppear:` to set the VC as a listener for that specific notification:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleButtonTap(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "ButtonTapped"), object: nil)
}
```

In the same view controller, add the `handleButtonTap:` method mentioned above. When the "ButtonTapped" notification comes in, it will execute this method.

```
@objc func handleButtonTap(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    //do something when the notification comes in
}
```

Don't forget to remove the view controller as an observer when it is no longer needed, like this:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```